# sbstract from a display table in django created using connection.cursor

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, django

I have displayed  two tables(i.e `table1` and `table2`) using `connection.cursor` from `SOURCE` table

**ISSUE:**

Now I have to subtract `table1(fields)-table2(fields)` and display the output as `table3`.

**PROGRAM:**

IN views.py

```
cursor1.execute('''select dummy as LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE,CUR AS CURRENCY,'$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_INS))) as LCR_NONOP_INS, '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_OP_INS))) as LCR_OP_INS, '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_UNINS)))as LCR_NONOP_UNINS, '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY,sum(LCR_OP_UNINS)))as LCR_OP_UNINS from (select *,(case when LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE='Corporate' then 'Non-Credit Financial Entities'else LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE end) as dummy from   DDA_BASED_S9_20150930) a group by CUR,dummy''')                                            cursor.execute('''select AFTERMEMO,CUR AS CURRENCY,'$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_INS))) as LCR_NONOP_INS,'$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_OP_INS))) as LCR_OP_INS, $'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_NONOP_UNINS))) as LCR_NONOP_UNINS, '$'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(MONEY, sum(LCR_OP_UNINS))) as LCR_OP_UNINS from (select *,(case when SIC_CODE = 7215 and LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'Non-Credit Financial Entities' then 'NonFinancialCorp' when LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE = 'Corporate' then 'Non-Credit Financial Entities' else LCR_CUSTOMER_TYPE end) as AFTERMEMO from  DDA_BASED_S9_20150930) a group by  CUR,AFTERMEMO''')

TABLE3=TABLE1-TABLE2
```

can anyone tell me how to do this...it will be very helpful thanks

Comment: Why are using SQL in Django?

Comment: Your question is tagged both [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server], which are competing RDBMS products from different suppliers (Oracle and Microsoft, respectively); it also tagged [tag:paypal], whereas your problem does not appear to have anything to do with the PayPal APIs; furthermore, your question is tagged [tag:python] and [tag:django] whereas your question appears (to my reading) to be purely about SQL.  Please remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: the reason i am using SQL, so that I can easily call the table from database by using simple query